# Mapping of webpack source maps for production in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

After deploying an app with `devtool: source-map` to production, i can't map the local source maps files i have in my machine with the .js source files on the server.

Basically, here the steps i follow for production:

1. I run a build with the commands `"./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.build.config.js --progress --colors --optimize-minimize --display-optimization-bailout"`, which produces the necessary .js and .map files of my app. I make a copy of this folder to my local desktop.
2. I remove all the .map files from the folder (i don't want to distribute them to the clients for obvious reasons) and ship it to production server.

My webpack build config is as below:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');
var fs = require("fs");
var WebpackOnBuildPlugin = require('on-build-webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: { 
        "myapp": './myapp/main-bootstrap.js',
        "vendor": [     
             'angular',
             'angular-ui-router',
             'angular-animate',
             'angular-translate',
             'angular-dynamic-locale',
             'angular-ui-bootstrap',
             './myapp-dep/angular-translate/2.15.1/angular-translate-loader-partial.min.js',
             './myapp-dep/environment/0.0.3/environment.js',
        ],
        "styles": [
            './myapp-dep/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css',
            './myapp/main.css'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "app"), 
        publicPath: './app/',
        filename: "[name]-[chunkhash:15].js", 
        chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].js'
    },
    module: { 
        rules: [] // my rules... too long to share and they are not important to this case
    },
    resolve: { 
        modules: ['myapp', 'node_modules'],
        alias: {
            bundle: path.resolve('./app'),
            root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'myapp'),
            dep: path.resolve(__dirname, 'myapp-dep')
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },

    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [  
      new WebpackShellPlugin({ onBuildStart: ['del "myapp-libs\\vendor*.js"', 'del "myapp-libs\\vendor*.map"', 'del app /Q /S'] }),
      new ExtractTextPlugin("styles-[chunkhash:15].css"),
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'vendor', filename: '../myapp-libs/vendor-[chunkhash:15].js' }),
      new webpack.NamedChunksPlugin(),
      new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'runtime' }),
      new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),

      new WebpackOnBuildPlugin(function(stats) {
          let assets = stats.toJson().assets; 
          let myappHash = assets.find(asset => asset.name.startsWith('myapp-')).name;
          let styleHash = assets.find(asset => /^styles-.*(\.css$)/g.test(asset.name)).name;
          let vendorHash = assets.find(asset => asset.name.startsWith('../myapp-libs/vendor-')).name.replace('../myapp-libs/', '');
          let runtimeHash = assets.find(asset => asset.name.startsWith('runtime-')).name;

          let index = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf8');
          index = index.replace(/<script src="app\/myapp-*\w*.js"><\/script>/i, '<script src="app/' + myappHash + '"></script>')
              .replace(/<link rel="stylesheet" href="app\/styles-*\w*.css">/i, '<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/' + styleHash + '">')
              .replace(/<script src="myapp-libs\/vendor-*\w*.js"><\/script>/i, '<script src="myapp-libs/' + vendorHash + '"></script>')
              .replace(/<script src="app\/runtime-*\w*.js"><\/script>/i, '<script src="app/' + runtimeHash + '"></script>');

          fs.writeFileSync('index.html', index, { flag: 'w' });
      })
    ]
};
```

Now, let's suppose a bug accour on my app.

How can i map the source maps i have with the .js files on the server? I already tried the `"add folder to workspace"` option but it doesn't seems to work for me (but it's probably due to my fault).

Comment: maybe check [this blog entry](https://itnext.io/using-sourcemaps-on-production-without-revealing-the-source-code-%EF%B8%8F-d41e78e20c89) on how some other dude did it